# sudo apt-get -f install #?

Tags: apt

I'm reading a line in some instructions and one of the steps is written as:

```
sudo apt-get -f install # Install dependencies and finish configuring the packages(s)
```

so i'm wondering is the "#" what i'm supposed to enter or should i be replacing with a list of packages that needed to be installed from the previous command which was this:

```
james@james-Galago:~/Desktop/Installers/Citrix$ sudo dpkg -i icaclient_13.1.0.285639_amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package icaclient.
(Reading database ... 580367 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack icaclient_13.1.0.285639_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking icaclient (13.1.0.285639) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of icaclient:
 icaclient depends on libgtk2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.12.0); however:
 icaclient depends on libcanberra-gtk-module:i386; however:

dpkg: error processing package icaclient (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 icaclient
```

I'm not sure if i need to do anything with these triggers listed above such as mime-support... I'm trying to configure my 14.04 to vpn using CAG:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CitrixICAClientHowTo

When I run:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

I get:

```
james@james-Galago:~/Desktop/Installers/Citrix$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libatk1.0-0:i386 libcanberra0:i386 libdatrie1:i386 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386
  libgraphite2-3:i386 libjasper1:i386 libpixman-1-0:i386 libspeex1:i386
  libtdb1:i386 libthai0:i386 libvorbisfile3:i386 libxcb-render0:i386
  libxcb-shm0:i386 libxerces-c3.1 libxmu6:i386
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  icaclient
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 37.4 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 580841 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing icaclient (13.1.0.285639) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply run

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

without anything additionally things. `#` is only the opener for a comment

To install packages, use

```
sudo apt-get install package_name
```

Replace `package_name` with the name of the package to install.

---

In your case

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

and if that not works

```
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module:i386
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386
```

---

An alternative to install the deb file is

```
software-center icaclient_13.1.0.285639_amd64.deb
```

---

From man `apt-get`

```
   -f, --fix-broken
        Fix; attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in
        place. This option, when used with install/remove, can omit any
        packages to permit APT to deduce a likely solution. If packages 
        are specified, these have to completely correct the problem. The 
        option is sometimes necessary when running APT for the first 
        time; APT itself does not allow broken package dependencies to 
        exist on a system. It is possible that a system's dependency 
        structure can be so corrupt as to require manual intervention 
        (which usually means using dpkg --remove to eliminate some of the 
        offending packages). Use of this option together with -m may 
        produce an error in some situations. Configuration Item: 
        APT::Get::Fix-Broken.
```

Comment: ah so the "#" was intended to be a comment...? i entered it and got the same result. Did not seem to install but think you answered the question. :)

Comment: Of course, you helped me last time so very happy to give you credit. Based on the output from my running that install command should the next command i try be:
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386

and then 
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module:i386

Comment: `apt-get install -f` sounds good as next command. :)

Comment: When I do that (with -f) it just removes the icaclient. Posted output up top.

Comment: No problem, install the dependencies first and after that the deb package.

Comment: Or use the `software-center icaclient_13.1.0.285639_amd64.deb`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26211/discussion-between-simgineer-and-a-b).

Comment: I would like to add that in case you change your mind about the said package (say `some_package`) and don't want to end up installing a whole bunch of packages to fix the unmet dependency error by doing `apt-get install -f`, simply do `apt-get remove some_package` and that will get rid of the unmet dependency error and also not install all the recommended packages to fix the break.